# Developing multiple Office Word VSTO Templates

Tags: c#, vba, vsto, ms-office, office-addins

I am trying to revamp lots of word templates from VBA (.dotm) to C# using VSTO & Visual Studio.

My question is if its possible to deploy multiple word templates with one VSTO installation or bundle so the user does not has to install VSTO for every template?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to create code free templates and a VSTO add-in.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of VSTO add-ins for Word - application-level and document-level add-ins. The Application level add-ins are not specific or linked to any document, they are installed for the application, not document. So, if you consider creating an application-level add-in for Word you may include any number of templates to the add-in. And there is no need to create a document-level add-in for each of them. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-word?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) for more information.

For document-level add-ins, see [Walkthrough: Create your first document-level customization for Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-document-level-customization-for-word?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp).

Comment: So for example I have a Word VSTO add-in that gets loaded everytime I open Word so the document has access to the classes etc. Lets say I have a template that should have custom logic that depends on the VSTO add-in when opening a new document. Does that mean that I still need a VSTO Template project for every template that has its own code?

Comment: You may mark template files with custom properties and read them when they are opened form the application-level add-in. Depending on the property value you may run actions.